# How do you generate service and other classes with T4 templates in EF Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

For years I have been using the Entity Framework in .Net applications using an EDMX file.  I was able to create T4 templates that could read the EDMX file and generate service classes and even controllers/views in MVC web apps.  I'm new to .Net Core (trying to use .Net 5.0), and I'm trying to figure out how I can do something similar with EF Core.  Ideally I'd have a T4 template in a separate Service project that could read the Data project and spit out Service classes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can import the Data project/assembly in your template with the assembly directive:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)YourProject\bin\Debug\YourSolution.DataProject.dll" #>
```

The downside is, if you declared classes as `internal` in the data project, it's very tricky to expose them to the T4 file.

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core, it is called [Scaffolding or Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding). It's most basic form is a simple command line call:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

EF Core 7 added support for [Custom Reverse Engineering Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates) once again using T4 (though not the EDMX file anymore). You essentially add the template package at the command line:

```
dotnet new install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Templates
```

then add the default templates to your project:

```
dotnet new ef-templates
```

This puts the default templates in `CodeTemplates/EFCore` where you can modify them as you choose. You can create multiple files by writing the `GenerationEnvironment` like so:

```
<#+
void OutputFileAbsolue(string absoluteFileName, bool clearCurrentOutput)
{
    File.WriteAllText(absoluteFileName, GenerationEnvironment.ToString());
    if (clearCurrentOutput) {
        GenerationEnvironment.Clear();
    }
}
#>
```